# Infinite nesting object with yup validation?

Tags: reactjs, formik, immutable.js, yup

I have an object that may contain children of the same type of object, potentially making it infinite nested.

```
{
  command: Yup.string(),
  children: [
             {
                 val1: Yup.string(),
                 val2: Yup.string(),
                 val3: Yup.string(),
             },
             {
                 command: Yup.string(),
                 children: [] // nesting children here
             }
            ]
}
```

how can I validate the above object with yup ?

Comment: I believe `lazy` is used for recursive validation like this: https://github.com/jquense/yup#lazyvalue-any--schema-lazy

Comment: Yeh, I'm sure we've to use lazy. but im confused how to validate 2 different object types in children array